# Swift selector method not being called

Tags: objective-c, swift, uibutton, action, selector

I create an action class to store the selectors, then addTarget to the button, but when I click it, the method in the action class has not been called

```
class ItemCardAction {
    
    static var shared: ItemCardAction = ItemCardAction()
    
    private init() {
       
    }
    
    var action: Selector = #selector(ItemCardAction.shared.buttonPressed)

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print("TEST")
        AppEngine.shared.updateItem(tag: sender.tag)
        AppEngine.shared.notigyAllObservers()
        //self.updateUI()
    }
}
```

add target

```
button.addTarget(self, action: ItemCardAction.shared.action, for: .touchDown)
```

Comment: Rather than `self`, try using `ItemCardAction.shared` as the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
button.addTarget(ItemCardAction.shared, action: ItemCardAction.shared.action, for: .touchUpInside)
```

If you look at `addTarget` method carefully, the first argument is target, when button receives (in this specific case) a touch inside event, iOS will look for the specified selector (specified in action parameter) in target specified. In your case you specified the target as `self` and clearly selector is not available in `self`'s scope hence nothing happens :)